# react router dom can't get page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using react with express using web pack but react router dom create an error i.e The null match problem.It can't get the page and the match is Null.
MY routes page code is: routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App  from './App.js';
import language from './language.js';
import Page    from './Page.js';
const Routes = () => (
<Router>
<div>
<Route path='/'         component={App} />
<Route path='/page'     component={Page} />
<Route path='/language' component={language} />
</div>
</Router>
)

console.log(typeof  Routes)
export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created sample snippet same as your code.

But its working fine. I am not getting any error

Check out this **[Snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/Z40mGZDB6)**